# How to use a variable define with a wildcard and the predicat Contains?

Tags: sql, t-sql

If i use the following command with the predicat Contain, i will get all the line where a word is starting by "clav"  (around 20):

```
SELECT name FROM CUSTOMERS_TABLE WHERE CONTAINS(name, '"clav*"');
```

Now if i'm using a variable, i get no line :

```
DECLARE @string nvarchar(20) = 'clav*';
SELECT name FROM CUSTOMERS_TABLE WHERE CONTAINS(name, @string);
```

I try to remove the wildcard and add a specific name > it's working.

Have you got an idea why a variable with a wildcar could not be use with the predicat CONTAINS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but maybe if you try to add the same text in the variable as in the first example you have...

So try to use this:

```
DECLARE @string nvarchar(20) = '"clav*"';
```

and not this:

```
DECLARE @string nvarchar(20) = 'clav*';
```